# How to create nav list with different buttons so when I click on the button the content/text will change according to the button I clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to programming so here is my basic question.

I know how to make a nav list but I don't know how to make it functional. For example, let's say that my navlist has 3 buttons: Home, About and Contact Me. How do I make my webpage to change from Home content between these 3 buttons??? What I mean is how do I get the different text/content when I click on About or Contact Me button?

Hope you understand what I mean. Must be really simple but I am just a begginer.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not using simple links? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: If you need a single page dynamic website then here ( http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicPage/#contact.php ) is a tutorial/example as it's a little complex. If you just want page to page navigation then it's very easy.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. A single page dynamic website. But when  click on the link I don't see the tutorial just a page that looks like what I was asking how to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most situations will also use CSS. If you want them all run in a list, you would use the following in your HTML:

```
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact-me.html">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

and your CSS style would be:

```
<style>
ul.navmenu {
/* enter your css UL MENU for your menu here*/
}
ul.navmenu li {
/* enter your css LIST for your menu here*/
}
ul.navmenu li a {
/* enter your css LINK for your menu here*/
}
</style>
```

You can look up "CSS list style" and get more information on how to change the looks of it.
Hope that helps you get started.

To get the buttons to change content, you need to add pages. For example, you would make the first page index.html (or index.php, or other page types), about.html, and contact-me.html. You have to create those pages so your links will go from one page to the next when you click on those links.

Comment: Alright! That's what I was looking for. So each link from my navbar is actually a new html page. I can keep the same CSS style for About.html and Contact-me.html right? If this is correct then I think you guys solved my problems! Btw, is this the usual way to create a website, like the most web developers would do it? Thanks again everybody! I love stackoverflow already!!!

Answer (score 2):

Usually those "buttons" would be *links*, which are created using the anchor tag (`<a>`). The page to go to is given by the `href` attribute on the tag, which is a URL. The URL can be absolute (`http://stackoverflow.com`) or relative (`about.html`).

Here's an example of a link:

```
<a href="about.html">About</a>
```

When the user clicks a link, the browser looks at the `href` and takes the user to that page.

I recommend working through any of a number of "beginning HTML" books and/or websites for a more thorough explanation.

If for some reason you absolutely want to use actual *buttons* (not links styled to look like buttons), you can do that, but it's not recommended. Here are two ways:

1. Make the button a `submit` button and put each one in its own form. The page the button will take the user to is defined as a URL in the `action` attribute of the form:

   ```
   <form action="about.html" method="GET">
       <input type="submit" value="About">
   </form>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <form action="about.html" method="GET">
       <button>About</button>
   </form>
   ```

   (If you use a `<button>` tag, you can have rich text on the button. Also, since the default type of a `<button>` is `submit`, you don't need `type="submit"` on it.)
2. Put an `onclick` handler on the button. I don't recommend this for several reasons, not least that they don't work if the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled, but that's rare.

   ```
   <input type="button" onclick="location = 'about.html'" value="About">
   ```

   or

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="location = 'about.html'">About</button>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I meant links not actual buttons! So I have to create a separate HTML document for each link??? Or it can be done all-in-one HTML document???

Comment: @user2397311 - technically you could get fancy and use javascript to change the page's content on-the-fly, but the vast majority of websites are usually simply composed of a network of HTML pages linked together ! I'd say you follow everyone else's advice and look up beginner tutorials for HTML and web design, such as on W3schools.

Comment: Thank you! I already went through codecademy web fundamentals which contains HTML and CSS tutorials so I am quite familiar with basics. However, either I missed this ot they didn't explain it clear enough that each link from a navbar is actually a new html document. Now when I know this my life's much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to web development, I would advice that you do not try to build such a common component as a navbar from scratch. Rather, use a framework, such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html). It has a [navbar](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar).

Comment: Thanks for advice! I heard about bootstrap already. This is very useful as well but I wanted to learn how to do it by myself from scratch.